# If instantiate structure, i can't deteche collider in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a random generator X structure and I won't make destroy objects if touch myself clone or X object, but the collider is not detecting. I checked the structure for generating to enable the collider or if the collider is a trigger, but all is okay. How I can fix it? Maybe because some objects are static in Inspector Unity?

My so-easy code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Косается?")] // touching?
    public bool TouchLog = false; // is default value

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collison) // check to touch
    {
        if(collison.gameObject.name == "Leaves_LOD0") // ObjectName_LOD level
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); // destroy object what touch tree
            Debug.Log("Сталкновение!"); // touching! (test message)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Physics isn't updated until the next `FixedUpdate` call.

In order to manually force physics updates after each `Instantiate` of your object you could use [`Physics.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html)

```
Physics.autoSimulation = false;

for (int i = 0; i <= what; i++)
{
    randomPosX = randomPos.Next(1, maxRangeX);
    randomPosZ = randomPos.Next(1, maxRangeZ);

    Instantiate(Object, new Vector3(randomPosX, 0.65f, randomPosZ), Quaternion.identity);

    Physics.Simulate(0f);
}

Physics.autoSimulation = true;
```

Comment: Where add the code lines?

Comment: @ForTankista as said right after where you spawn the objects using `Instantiate`

Comment: O, derHugo hi, i rememebr you!

Comment: I add script for generating, ok?

Comment: This is don't working =(.

Comment: I get warning:  Physics.Simulate(...) was called with a negative time. This is not supported therefore the simulation was not run.
UnityEngine.Physics:Simulate (single)