# Unity Spawning Then Box Cast

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm instantiating an object and then within the same fame performing a box cast. The box cast isn't detecting the spawned object, does the system require a frame to update the physics system or something? Could this lead to unpredictable behaviour?

`distributedObject = Instantiate( _distributableObjects.Get(), distributionZone.GetPosition(transform.position), Quaternion.identity);`

`int collidedObjects = Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc (objectPosition + (castDirection * _castOffsetDistance),  (_castSize / 2), _collidedObjects, Quaternion.identity, _castLayers);`

This is currently ideal for my current system, but I don't want it to lead to unpredictable behaviour in the future.

Comment: Yes it needs a frame .. you can use [`Physics.Simulate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74288011/7111561) to immediately force a physics update .. this is global though .. depends on your exact use case .. you are fine if this is not during game play but during a static setup phase